# Forge UI - how do I create a hook to update a state property?

Tags: hook, atlassian-forge

I'm trying  to set a state property by using a [Forge UI kit hook](https://developer.atlassian.com/platform/forge/ui-kit-hooks-reference/), like this:

```
const sortOrder [orderBy, setSortOrder] = useAction(
    ( currentSortOrder, nextSortOrder: string ) => nextSortOrder, "word");
```

Forge UI hooks work in a similar way to React hooks. An intro video for how to use a Forge UI hook is here (watch from 15:45 - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WoSR7qQkgn4)

I'm getting the error `An argument for 'initialValue' was not provided`, but I've used the syntax according to the above video, and I intend `"word"` to be the initial value. How do I correct the code for the hook?

Answer (score 0):

Doh

const [orderBy, setSortOrder] = useAction(
( currentSortOrder, nextSortOrder: string ) => nextSortOrder, "word");